# How to use @tanstack/vue-query with graphql codegen in ts? Because there is no typescript-vue-query plugin similar to typescript-react-query for vue

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, graphql, react-query, vue-query

Please suggest if possible in some way.

I have tried to change the import path from react-query to vue-query after typescript-react-query has done with it. But I didn't able to make it work (actually I don't know how).

myplugin.js - copied from codegen documentation

```
module.exports = {
  plugin(schema, documents, config, info) {
    const typesMap = schema.getTypeMap()
 
    return Object.keys(typesMap).join('\n')
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Great that you've tried something, but you haven't shown us what. Please [edit] your post with the (non-working) code, i.e. a [mre]. That way, it is easier for us to be able to help you.